# Close drop down menu after hover?

Tags: javascript

looking for a simple script that will close on click a dropdown menu that opens on hover...thanks very much!

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>Product images <span class="wsarrow"></span></a>
    <div class="wsmegamenu clearfix ">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <h3 class="title">Product Features</h3>
    <div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper"><img src="{T_THEME_PATH}/navbar_fancy/images/image02.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
    <p class="wsmwnutxt">Lorem Ipsum is dummy text of the printing specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also typesetting in the the contantly with desktoncluding.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <h3 class="title">Blog Article </h3>
    <div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper"><img src="{T_THEME_PATH}/navbar_fancy/images/image03.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
    <p class="wsmwnutxt">Lorem Ipsum is dummy text of the printing specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also typesetting in the the contantly with desktoncluding.</p>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: You might want to do some research on this, try looking at MDN or W3Schools.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your code has anything to do with your question but hear ya go:  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

No JS needed.

Comment: thank you very much for your response, much appreciated! the code i posted above is from a purchased navbar, all of the drop down menus open automatically when hovered (js)... i was hoping that i could add a script to the bottom of the file which would add a close on click function... a google search tuned up some examples which worked to some extent, but not completely, and i think it has to do with me not knowing what div to reference from the above code in terms of editing the small scripts.